# FPDF AddLink not working

Tags: php, fpdf

I am using fpdf AddLink function to create an internal link and at the end of all page generation I am using the below function to reorder the pages after that Links are not working. What could be the reason.Thanks

```
public function movePages($oldIndex, $nrPages, $newIndex) {

    $newPages = array();

    for($i=1; $i<=sizeof($this->pages); $i++) {
        if($i < $newIndex) {

            $newPages[$i] = $this->pages[$i];
        } elseif($i < $newIndex+$nrPages) {
            $newPages[$i] = $this->pages[$oldIndex+$i-$newIndex+1];
        } else {
            $newPages[$i] = $this->pages[$i-$nrPages];
        }

        $newPages[$i] = str_replace('{pageNr}', $i, $newPages[$i]);
    }

    $this->pages = $newPages;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Right.

Just ran into this myself. Found a solution.

When the page switching occurs, it appears that the text elements are stored in one kind of mapping scheme, while the visual elements are stored in another. When the page is switched, the text moves and the hotspots do not. They're still linked and work, but are hard to find now on their original page.

The trick I found that worked was to store the Abscissa co-ordinates and page number to link to in an array (hash indexed by the original page number), do the switching within a loop (manually setting the page number of `$this->page` for each link) and use `$this->Link($x, $y, $w, $h, $link)` to make the hotspot where I want it to and then `$this->SetLink($link, 0, $pageNo)` to set it to the right page.

Then reset the page count or it won't render properly.